# cleaning up heavy use of template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a set of classes in a logging framework used by project A and B. I am refactoring the framework so it can be used in project B and C. The refactoring mainly consists of giving everything template parameters: project A might run on an embedded device with poor/no STL implemenatation, while B and C just run on a pc, but B is single threaded while C uses multithreading.

This works well, but results in what seems to me an awfull lot of template parameters and a rather ugly typedef mess. I need like 20 lines to typedef all classes I'm going to use, and there are also lots of classes taking a template parameter they do not use themselves, but is needed to be able to typedef another class they do use (which is not per se a bad thing, but in the end everything starts to llok really complicated). Another problem is that when I want to add some functionality to class A and it requires adding a container, class A needs an extra template paramater. As a result, all other classes seeing/using class A suddenly also need that extra parameter leading to a domino effect.

Slightly exaggerated example:

```
template< class string, class map, class mutex >
class MessageDestination
{
  typedef Message< string, map > message_type;
  virtual void Eat( const message_type& ) = 0;
}

template< class string, class map, class stream >
class MessageFormatter
{
  typedef Message< string, map > message_type;
  virtual void Format( const message_type&, stream& ) = 0;
}

template< class string, class map, class containerA,
          template< class, class > containerB, template< class, class > class queue, class allocator >
class ThreadedMessageAcceptor
{
  typedef Message< string, map > message_type;
  typedef MessageDestination< string, map > destination_type;
  typedef containerB< destination_type, allocator > destinations_type;
  typedef queue< message_type, allocator > messages_type;
};
```

I can think of some techniques to clean this up, but I'm having a hard time deciding what one or which combination to use. StackOverFlow, your help will be appreciated!

Here's the first solution I thought of, joining parameters together into the type they'll eventually form:

```
template< class message, class mutex >
class MessageDestination
{
  virtual void Eat( const message& ) = 0;
}
```

This makes it simpler, but doesn't it at the same time it kind of hides what message actually is? Suppose a user wants to provide an implementation, he does not directly see that message has to use a certain string type etc.

Another technique I thougt about, but cannot recall having seen before somwhere which makes it look suspicious, is simply defining everything in a single struct and passing that as single template parameter to everything:

```
struct MyTemplateParameters
{
  typedef std::string string;
  typedef std::map map;
  typedef std::queue queue;
  typedef LightMutex mutex;
  template< class A, class B >
  struct DefineContainerB
  {
    typedef containerB< A, B >::type;
  }
  //....
};

template< class parameters >
class MessageDestination
{
  typedef Message< parameters > message_type;
  virtual void Eat( const message_type& ) = 0;
};

template< class parameters >
class ThreadedMessageAcceptor
{
  typedef Message< parameters > message_type;
  typedef MessageDestination< parameters > destination_type;
  typedef parameters::DefineContainerB< destination_type, parameters::allocator >::type destinations_type;
};
```

This is nice as it allows specifying everything at one single point, and the typedefs to all classes will all be class XXX< MyTemplateParameters >, but again, it gives me an uneasy feeling. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “other” technique is very common in C++. The parameters class is usually called a “**[trait class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traits_class)**”.

This is the way to go (why does it give you an uneasy feeling?). It is used pervasively in the Boost libraries and other C++ libraries. Even the standard library uses it, e.g. in the `std::basic_string` class.

---

An equally well-established alternative are metafunctions. At its most basic, a metafunction is a “function” that operates on types rather than objects. So where a function takes value arguments and returns a value, a metafunctions takes template arguments and “returns” a type:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity {
    typedef T type;
};
```

The metafunction is used (“invoked”) like a normal type definition.

```
typedef identity<int>::type mytype; // or
identity<int>::type x;
```

Not very useful in this case. But consider the following common metafunction:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_const {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_const<T const> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

This can be used to make an arbitrary type (in particular a template argument) non-const. This is actually a type I’m currently using in a project: I have a class that accepts both const and non-const types and offers appropriate interfaces. However, *internally* I need to store a non-const reference. Simple, I just use the following code in my class:

```
typename remove_const<T>::type& _reference;
```

(The `typename` is required because `T` is a template argument and that makes `remove_const<T>::type` a *dependent type*. Your above example code is actually omitting quite a few required `typename`s – it won’t compile on several modern compilers!)

Now, how to apply this to your problem?

Create two empty *marker types* that specify whether your types are used on an embedded device or on a compliant compiler:

```
struct Embedded { };
struct Compliant { };
```

Now you can define your classes in terms of these, e.g.:

```
template<typename Spec>
class ThreadedMessageAcceptor
{
    typedef Message< Spec > message_type;
    typedef MessageDestination< Spec > destination_type;
    typedef typename Allocator< destination_type, Spec >::type allocator_type;
    typedef typename ContainerB< destination_type, allocator_type, Spec >::type destinations_type;
};
```

Here, `Spec` will be either `Compliant` or `Embedded`. So to use it on a standards compliant compiler, write:

```
ThreadedMessageAcceptor<Compliant> x;
```

The class uses the following metafunctions:

```
template <typename T, typename Spec>
struct Allocator { };

template <typename T, typename Alloc, typename Spec>
struct ContainerB { };
```

You need to remember to specialize them appropriately for your target specifications, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
struct Allocator<T, Compliant> {
   typedef std::allocator<T> type;
};

template <typename T, typename Alloc>
struct ContainerB<T, Alloc, Compliant> {
    typedef std::vector<T, Alloc> type;
};
```

This already shows that a metafunction may have arbitrarily many arguments besides the `Spec` (which I’ve put last on a whim – but its placement should be consistent).

To be sure, this is more code than when using a single trait class but it has lower cohesion, logically separates concerns and is easier to reuse.

Comment: Modern trends go towards avoiding blobs of traits and rather providing traits as separate metafunctions, each one with a single `type` or `value` result, so I would not say "this is the way to go". Still "this is A way to go" seems good enough.

Comment: @David: I’m all for metafunctions – in fact, I nearly posted this as the answer instead – but considering the sheer bulk of types in the code above, I still think that traits are a better solution in this case. And I wouldn’t say that traits are *generally* deprecated in favour of metafunctions.

Comment: @Konrad: traits do definitely ring a bell, no idea why I didn't make the link (maybe I thought they were more used in ways like traits< some_type >, not just like the MyTemplateParameters I wrote without any template parameter)
The reason for the uneasy feeling is that for example MessageDestination has no business with DefineContainerB. But I just realized this could be solved by having multiple traits sets where the more complicated ones inherit a simpler one.
Care to elaborate on how metafunctions could be used here?